# update an already existing install

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade, package, patch

How to update an already existing install of a product with a new install package? Right now when there is an already installed version on my PC, the setup package says that another version was already installed and just exists. So I have to uninstall the old version and install the new one. But I want the new version to upgrade the old version to new version. How do I do that? 
I know that the product code must match. I think there is something to do with the upgrade code also.
Both answers for visual studio setup projects and wix setup projects are welcome, but I think that there is the same principle beyond them all.

Comment: Start from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369786.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, to make the install package upgrade itself, the *ProductCode* must be different in each package. *UpgradeCode* must match.

You should also configure `<Upgrade>` element or use `<MajorUpgrade>` in WiX.

For an example, look at **[Checking for Oldies](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson4.php#4.1)** section in the WiX tutorial:

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep your Upgrade code constant across the whole project.

Also, WIX will consider only Major and Minor version changes.

Check out this site [WIX Upgrades](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson4.php)

Comment: Unfortunately, this link is dead now.